# Tips for humor writing

Tags: brainstorming, humor

Are there any techniques you can use while brainstorming to find humor to include in an article?

Comment: I'm guessing you want something stronger than "be funny"?

Comment: Yeah, tactical advice

Comment: Use your own dark humor. Embed your mind into your works. That's what I do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) Pick any one item and take it to an extreme.

"Organizing is good."

- Okay, can I alphabetize my spices?
  *(bad example. I actually do that.)*
- Uh, can I sort my vegetable drawer by
  size and then by color?
- How about putting the living room furniture in rainbow order?
- Where do I file the cat, under P for 
  Pet, F for Felix domesticus, or O for
  Ollie (his name)?

2) Slip in some judicious puns. For example, if you're comparing shredders, you might write that you don't want to get snippy, but Brand X is really a cut above, and anyone who doesn't think so simply isn't all that sharp. (Caveat scriptor: your mileage may vary.)

3) Take a metaphor and run it off a cliff of absurdity.

"Okay, so imagine that your desk is an elephant, and you're going to eat it one bite at a time. So first you start with a foot, represented by a desk drawer. The file folders are the toes, and the tabs are the toenails. Any punched-out holes, lost post-its, orphaned notes, or faded fax cover sheets would be elephant toejam. That's probably kind of nasty-smelling, but don't worry; just crumple the whole thing up and make a toejam football out of it, and throw it into the nearest wastebasket."

Answer (score 7):

When I write jokes I'll often begin with stream-of-consciousness "brain vomit," putting every possible thought to paper.  I'll mark places I *think* people would laugh with an asterisk.  This is more organic than just trying to think of funny things.

After this you can cross out everything that lacks an asterisk, and rework your sentences so that the asterisk comes at the end.  After this you can present your laugh lines to others and learn how well you judged the asterisks.  Then practice practice practice.

I know it's a unique technique (as far as I know I'm the only one who does it) but it works well for me.

```
I'm really bad at oranges.* 
I read if you put your thumb in by the stem you can pull off big chunks,
But what I do is just eat apples.*
God made convenient fruit.*
You can just bite it* and your hands don't get sticky.*
Why would you eat coconuts on an island that also has bananas?*
"I didn't bring my machete to lunch.*
I wish there were an alternative.*"
Banana ka-bobs,* banana creole,* banana gumbo.*
Pan fried,* stir fried,* deep fried.*
People die from coconuts.*
Apples help you discover gravity.*
```

Once you've got a presentable "joke framework," I've found that *asking other people for ideas* is a great way to improve/replace the jokes.

Answer (score 5):

Here I roughly translate and sum up some advices from Daniele Luttazzi, an italian satirist ([original text here](http://www.danieleluttazzi.it/node/384)) who learned from the best, like Lenny Bruce and Josh Carlin. (Sorry for any mistake, please edit).

---

The punchline must be a suprise with respect to the preamble. If the surprise is weak the humor will be weak. If the surprise is awkward the humor will be weak too. The difficult part is balancing these two parts (preamble and punchline).

Wordplay is difficult, more than you think (but anglosaxon humor might be quite different in this aspect).

There is a fashion in jokes, too. What made our grandparents laugh might not be that good anymore.

Keep the punchline as dry as possible. Less words is better, except when this hurts the rhythm.

A good joke is based on an idea, not on a commonplace. If you crack a joke on something you are not well enough informed on, you won't make people laugh. On the other hand if the joke refers to very specific subjects no one, except a bunch of specialists, will get it.

What elicits a laugh is the technique of the joke, not its content. When you retell a joke in other words it usually doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Read things that you find funny.  Eventually, humor will organically bubble up in your own writing.  This is the best way, as forced humor usually comes off bad.

Comedy, as a genre, is hard to get right.  Drama is easy.

Anyway, the book that had the biggest impact on humor in my writing is this: **The Signet Book of American Humor**

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0451210581?ie=UTF8&tag=httpwwwgmoone-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0451210581](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451210581)

Buy it used, stick it in your pocket and read it when you're stuck somewhere (the dentist's office, a meeting, etc...)  Don't miss the George Carlin bits.

Seek out humor in other writing and learn from there.

Answer (score 4):

**I think the most important thing is to figure out what kind of humor are YOU good at.**

Lauren Ipsum's and Cody Hess's suggestions are how THEY get people to laugh. Gmoore's suggestion is a good one, figure out what makes you laugh, what you think is funny, and then try to duplicate that with your own ideas.

Look at the way you create humor when interacting with other people, and try to deliver that into your writing. If your audience is known (friends, family, colleagues) you might find humor in inside jokes or shared experiences. If you are going for a broader (ie anonymous) audience you should figure out how your humor plays to strangers (people who don't know your brand of humor).

Answer (score 3):

Terry Pratchett is the writer who springs to my mind (a product of the type of book I read I guess), and it always seems like his humor comes from:

- The characters having at least one defining "crazy" attribute, and they stay true to that.
- The situation being a combination of at least two separate very different but equally absurd story threads.

And mostly, his **dialogue**. Wit and Stupidity together.

Comment: PTerry's writing is a good example of humourous writing out of realistic responses. Most humour comes from unexpected responses, but good humour in fiction comes from realistic responses. You alluded to this by saying characters stay true their crazyness.

Answer (score 3):

Douglas Adams was a master at it: surprising the reader (and the characters); taking clichés and pushing them to the extreme; using anthropomorphism (objects that seems to act on their own); using nonsense, absurdity, craziness. I have read the only trilogy in five volumes (H2G2) a long time ago and just re-read it in French (my native tongue) and I was delighted.
Beside the humor, the guy was good at making a global, consistent plot, which isn't to disdain...

Answer (score 2):

http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Uncyclopedia:How_To_Be_Funny_And_Not_Just_Stupid

There are some good tips in this link, even if it's slightly skewed towards the format of it's own site, but I'll summarise the main points:

## Going all-out true/untrue/random is rarely funny. You need a clever blend.

Bad Example:

"Donald Trump was born in the year 548723BC to Theodore Roosevelt and a turnip"

Better Example:

"Donald Trump frequently got into trouble in kindergarten for bullying due to his habit of building walls out of Lego blocks and attempting to make Mexican classmates 'pay for it'"

## Repetition

It's stupid but it works. just repeat a point intermittently in your block of text.

## Misdirection

This is where you take a fairly normal block of writing and veer off into a completely different direction entirely.

Example:

"Hitler's crimes included the murder of over 6 million people, the annexation of several European countries, the incitement of hatred across millions of German people, and a moustache that should have seen him hung by the fashion police years ago"

Or:

"Playing poker against Bob was never a challenge. His face was like a book. So much so that during the last game, I hurt him by trying to turn the page."

## Choice of words

Oftentimes, it's a lot better to not state things outright but to exercise your lexicon a little bit. 'I realised that Edith was stupid' isn't as good as 'It dawned on me that the question of how Edith graduated high-school may well become the next Wonder of the World.'

## Repetition

It's stupid but it works. just repeat a point intermittently in your block of text.

## Understatement of the century

Pretty much as it sounds. "The Holocaust was a slight inconvenience to the German Jewish population"

## Reversal

"Man-spider is an incredible superpowered spider with the ability to file taxes"

## Repetition

It's stupid but it works. just repeat a point intermittently in your block of text.

Answer (score 0):

mm, I think it's hard to absorb funny material in a brainstorm without later including or at least paraphrasing it - which may or may not be the effect you are after. I have in my Reader lots of funny steams that I dip into when I need a break: lolcatz and dogs, Dilbert, Coding Horror, Worse than Failure.

Often times I do search images for "subject + lol".

Answer (score 0):

What makes people laugh?  Then use that.

Since you are working on How-To manuals, I think the best way to make good comedy in your books is to **explain the topic to people you know**, but add in jokes as you're doing it.  Chances are what your audience finds funny, others will find funny as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're either funny or you're not.
If you watch a lot of humor, you may start thinking like a certain comedian and it could help.